# weighted mean (%) of dichotomous variables in expss tables

Tags: r, expss, weighting

I want to create a weighted mean of a dichotomous variables (0 or 1) using expss packages. AND the results will be presented in percentage. These dichotomous variables contain missing values.

fisrt of all, i create a function :

```
tableau = function (Q, banner,titre) {

banner <- df %>% 
  tab_cols(a2,a3)

    eval.parent(substitute(
  {
    banner %>%
      tab_cells (list(Q)) %>%
   tab_weight(weighting_var) %>%
    tab_stat_fun("%" = function (x)  mean(x,na.rm = TRUE)*100) %>%
     tab_pivot() %>% 
      drop_empty_columns() %>%
      tab_transpose() %>% 
      set_caption(titre) #%>%
    # custom_format() 
  }
))
}
```

When i use this function:

```
tableau(list(i1.3_1,i1.3_2,i1.3_3,i1.3_4,i1.3_5,i1.3_6),banner,'TABLE 1')
```

i get this message :

```
`weight` is provided but function`%` doesn't have formal `weight` argument
```

how can I modify my function to make sure that the results are weighting?

Answer (score 0):

You need formal weight parameter in your function.
In your case it looks like this: `"%" = function (x, weight)  w_mean(x, weight = weight, na.rm = TRUE)*100`